# Get value of dropdownlist in view and use in controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a dropdownlist in my view:

```
<form action="./sort" method="post">
        <div class="sort-dropdown">
            <select name="sort">
                <option value="">Sort</option>
                <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
                <option value="desc">Descending</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I want to get the value when user choose in dropdownlist, in my controller, I tried:

```
$sort = $request->sort;
```

But when I choose in dropdownlist and use dd($sort), it return null. How I can get the value? Thank you!

Update:
Here is my full controller:

```
public function search(Request $request) {
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $sort = $request->sort;

    dd($search, $sort);
    die;

    $result = $this -> model -> getSearch($search, $sort);

    $processData['processData'] = $result;

    return view('datatracking', $processData);

}
```

Comment: what did you choose?? did you try `$sort = $request->get('sort');`?

Comment: I choose Asc or Desc to display value with dd() but it just return null, I use $sort = $request->get('sort'); before. After search some post in here, I changed but not work too

Comment: show your controller, and moreover why did you have this trailing single dot in your action?

Comment: Because my url is http://localhost/activiti/public/procinsttable. If don't have that dot in my action, when I search something, my url will be error. Btw, I updated my post which have controller

Answer (score 0):

use this and dd($array_name);

```
$array_name->sort = $request->sort;
```

Comment: Still error. It say: "Creating default object from empty value"

Answer (score 0):

You can get this from array

```
$request['sort'];
```

Comment: sorry but it's still null

Comment: I think the issue is in your form action.

Comment: <form action="your route here" method="GET" >
                {{ csrf_field() }}          </form>

Comment: I think it's ok now. My only problem now is the url. After I search, my url is: http://localhost/activiti/public/search?search=process, I choose asc sort and my url become: http://localhost/activiti/public/sort?sort=asc. It sort with my full data not searched data.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is not getting submitted. To submit the form you need to add javascript .

```
<form action="./sort" method="post" >
                    <div class="sort-dropdown">
                        <select name="sort"  onchange="this.form.submit()">
                            <option value="">Sort</option>
                            <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
                            <option value="desc">Descending</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: it's still null :(

Answer (score 0):

You can always take advantage of javascript's [***onchange***](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp). Maybe spice it up with a [switch case?](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

**Routes/web.php**

```
Route::post('./sort', 'YourController@show')->name('sort-records');
```

**Blade:**

```
<form action="./sort" method="post">
    <!-- pass your csrf token --> 
    @csrf

    <div class="sort-dropdown input-group">

        <!-- note the use of the onchange --> 
        <select name="sort" id="sort" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="">Sort</option>
            <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
            <option value="desc">Descending</option>
        </select>

    </div>
</form>
```

**YourController:**

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
     switch ($request->sort)
     {
         case "asc":
         // Grab your records accordingly
         $variable = $x;
         break;

         case "desc":
         // Grab your records accordingly
         $variable = $y;
         break;

         default:
         // Set a default sort option
         $variable = $z;
         break;
     }

     return view('datatracking', $variable);  
}
```

Comment: I think it's ok now. My only problem now is the url. After I search, my url is: localhost/activiti/public/search?search=process, I choose asc sort and my url become: localhost/activiti/public/sort?sort=asc. It sort with my full data not searched data.

Comment: Start up another question @Tomato and I'd be happy to flesh it out with you! That's a separate question from this original one.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select name="sort" id="sort" class="form-control" >
        <option value="Sort">Sort</option>
        <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
        <option value="desc">Descending</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.